# File "<string>" SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, string, syntax-error, pydroid

I've recently been trying to code a program which plays domino with two players and with input, but apparently my syntax is flawed at the line where I define a function. I think it might be because of my near-zero experience with coding , but after I've searched on the internet, I haven't found any solution.
Here's the code :

```
def comptage():
    occurences_of_numbers=[]
    for i in range(7):
        a=0
        for k in range(7):
            if i in list(hand[k]):
                a=a+1
        occurences_of_numbers.append(a)
    return(occurences_of_numbers)


File "<string>", line 36
    def comptage():
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This function counts the numbers of occurrences of the numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) in the tuples representing the dominos in the list named `hand`. I then use the function for other functions.

```
available_draws=14
opponent_hand=7
while comptage()[list(board[0])[0]]==0 and comptage()[list(board[len(board)-1])[1]]==0:
    inpt_list=list(map(int,input('   Quel domino pioché ?')))
    M.append((inpt_list[0],inpt_list[1]))
    available_draws=available_draws-1


#board is a tuple list representing the board


def riposte():
    probability=[]
    for i in range(7):
        b=0
        for k in range(len(board)):
            if i in list(board[k]):
                b=b+1
        probability.append((7-comptage()[i]-b)/(28-len(hand)-len(board))*(opponent_hand/(opponent_hand+available_draws)))
    return(probability)
```

This error popped up after I changed something in the `riposte()` function (I added the `b` characteristic). But it shows the mistake for the `comptage()` function. I don't know why it showed that.
I've tried changing the code a bit, rewriting it, and using other variants, but the error message stands still.

The rest of the code is : (some unfinished stuff)

```
zero=[]
one=[]
two=[]
three=[]
four=[]
five=[]
six=[]
all_the_dominos=[zero,one,two,three,four,five,six]
for i in range(7):
    for k in range(7):
        all_the_dominos[i].append((i,k))

hand=[]
for i in range(1,8):
    input_list=list(map(int,input('   Domino '+str(i)+' ?')))
    hand.append((input_list[0],input_list[1]))
print(hand)

for i in range(7):
    for k in range(7):
                if hand[i] in all_the_dominos[k]:
                    del all_the_dominos[k][all_the_dominos[k].index(hand[i])]
                elif tuple(reversed(list(hand[i]))) in all_the_dominos[k]:
                    del all_the_dominos[k][all_the_dominos[k].index(tuple(reversed(list(hand[i]))))

board=[(6,1),(1,2),(2,6),(6,6)]

#example of a board 

available_draws=14
opponent_hand=7
while input('   Pioche adverse ?')=='oui':
    opponent_hand=opponent_hand+1
    available_draws=available_draws-1
```

The only thing that comes after what is problematic is the last bit.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

**!! UPDATE !!**

I've trisd another version of the compatge function, but it still shows the same error :

```
def comptage():
    F=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(7):
        for k in range(len(M)):
            if i in list(M[k]):
                F[i]=F[i]+1
    return(F)
```

But something's strange : i can't even define a variable !

```
a=0

File "<string>", line 34
    a=0
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I definitely think there is a problem with my phone because i've downloaded several other coding programs and always got the same error.
It's strange because it was working fine and all of a sudden, it doesn't allow me to do anything.

Well maybe there's just a problem with the code  but i really don't think so.

Comment: Can you share the full code? I believe there is an error above with mismatched paranthesis

Comment: For easiness to read and debug your code it's better to write self explanatory names for variables, like `board` instead of `J`. Also, it's a convention to use Capital letter at the beginning for classes. For variables it's better `board`, `domino_board` or `dominoBoard`. Trust me, they seem unnecessary longer, but yourself-in-three-months is going to be thankful with  yourself-now.

Comment: Okay, will do !

Comment: Check the line before the one where you're getting an error and make sure all the parentheses and other brackets are properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 1 more closing parenthesis (`)`) than opening parenthesis (`(`) on this line: `P.append((7-comptage()[i]-b)/(28-len(M)-len(J))*(aM/(aM+p)))`

Comment: In fact, that was a mistake, but the error shows anyway 

Comment: Actually, I've rechecked the parenthesis, but it is not a mistake : it allows the long operation to fit in the parenthesis of the `append` function.

Comment: @AlexandrePalamodov Maybe there's an open parenthesis missing somewhere, then?

Comment: Well that could be the case but I've searched for it a lot and didn't find anything. On top of that, there may be another problem (new update).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found the problem : there was just a missing bracket . I'm new to Python so  I didn't pay enough attention even though I thought I did.

Comment: Could you detail the mistake you made and post the working code? A comment that it works should be reserved for the comments section, and not be added as an 'answer'.

Comment: Ok noted ! The mistake I made was that I forgot a closing bracket on the following line : ```del all_the_dominos[k][all_the_dominos[k].index(tuple(reversed(list(hand[i]))))```
But still, it was strange that the error message showed the lines after the mistake as the real mistakes.